# How can I set the HTML width attribute using a field of an object in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am working on an Angular application and I have the following problem.

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="text-center p-title">
    Partners
</div>
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div [class.darker-bg]="partner.name === '4ChangeMakers'" 
    (click)="openDialog(partner)"
    *ngFor="let partner of partners" class="col-xs-12 rounded py-4 partner col-md-3">
        <img style="max-height: 400px" width="100%" [src]="partner.img" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

it iterate on the **partners** array and display these logs using the **partner.img** property of the current object of the iteration:

[image]

It works fine.

As you can see in the previous HTML code the width of these images is fixed and it is the same for all these images **width="100%"**

What I want to do is to externalize also the value of the width property in order to allow different width values for different logos images.

So I added this new field to all the objects defined into the **partners** array, in this way:

```
export const partners = [
    {
    img: '/assets/partners/slowfashion.png',
    width: "100%",
    name: 'Slow Fashion World',
    url: 'https://slowfashionworld.com/',
    bio: 'SFW is a global community committed to slowing down the fashion world, one story at a time . As a  marketing and communications agency, SFW supports businesses to lead with transparency and communicate their positive actions to transform the fashion industry.\nSFW is known to join communities around social entrepreneurship and fashion, encouraging experiences that involve  diverse voices creating action around  sustainable and slow fashion. SFW has a vision to create one world where co-creation, collaboration and taking action as a community becomes the norm.'
    },
    {
    img: '/assets/partners/4CM.png',
    width: "100%",
    name: '4ChangeMakers',
    url: 'https://www.4changemakers.com/',
    bio: '4ChangeMakers is a community for the new generation of high-impact entrepreneurs that wishes to grow a profitable business while simultaneously doing something good for the world. The founders,  Sina & Fernando are two rebels who dropped out of the traditional business world to believe in the extraordinary power of business as a force for good. Their combined corporate experience has equipped them with the strategies, tools and tactics used by top performing companies. Now, they dedicate their lives to empowering a new generation of entrepreneurs to start and grow sustainable businesses.'
    },
    {
    img: '/assets/partners/5bits.png',
    width: "60%",
    name: 'Fivebits',
    url: 'https://5bits.it/#home-section',
    bio: 'FIVEBITS is a multidisciplinary team made from the synergy of IT professionals counting years of national and international experience. The young and curious spirit, the harmonic evolution, and the adaptive approach are the company\'s main pillars.\r\nTowards objectives, Fivebits aims to:\r\nEmpower your ideas through technology\r\nConvert your business needs into fully functionally software\n\rProvide expert guidance through the design and production of efficient ICT solutions\n\rBe your focal point for ICT.\n'
    }
]
```

As you can see, now all the **partners** array objects have their own specific **width** property (as percentage).

Then I tried to change the previous HTML code in order to use this property instead the fixed **100%** value. I tried in this way:

```
<img style="max-height: 400px" width="partner.width" [src]="partner.img" alt="">
```

basically I am trying to use the specific **partner.width** value for the **width** attribute. But it is not working. I obtain no error but now the result is ugly:

[image]

Using the Chrome console it is rendering:

it is taking the **partner.width** string instead the value of this partner.width field.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
[style.width.%]="partner.width"
```

Also remove `%` from `width: "100%",` to be just `width: "100",`